# Why do I get a faint border around css circles in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a div with a 50% radius and equal heights and widths. It has a border that is the same color as the background of the parent element. Outside of this border there's a thin outline of div background color that kinda looks like anti-aliasing.

Why does this happen? It seems to be present in all versions of IE.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVMwxR

```
<body>
    <div id="inner"></div>  
</body>
```

and CSS:

```
#inner {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 40px solid white;
    background: red;
    width: 20rem;
    height: 20rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: can't seem to recreate this. Can you add a screenshot? Opened the pen in IE and worked fine.

Comment: I can confirm the issue on IE11 Windows 8.1. Same happens on emulation of IE10 in dev tools

Comment: Similar questions - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=border+radius+bleed

Answer (score 1):

I can't offer an immediate solution using `border` but an alternative is to use a `box-shadow` instead.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#inner {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 40px white;
  background: red;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

body {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
 <div id="inner"></div>
```

Note: A box-shadow doesn't add dimension to your element so it's not an absolute replacement.